# Codename One - Dialog button

Tags: codenameone

**Situation**

I have the following Dialog added manually to a GUI built app:

```
Dialog.show("Delete","Are you sure?","Yes","No")
```

When the user presses "Yes" the app does its work deleting the item from a list

**Question**

Where should I include the "delete" code? Do I need an Action Listener to implement those actions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dialog can return boolean (true or false), change your code to use `if statement`:

```
if (Dialog.show("Delete","Are you sure?","Yes","No")) {
    //add the code to delete item here
}
```